# Como extraer los datos del arreglo con el ciclo while

Tags: c#

Soy nuevo en esto, no entiendo muy bien como hacerlo, con el `for` me funciono, pero con el `while` no tengo idea, quiero que me imprima:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
//declaracion del arreglo multidimensional con valores
            int[,] arregloMultidimencionalValores = {
             {1, 3, 4},
             {5, 8, 9}

            };
//imprimiendo la posicion de un valor del arreglo multidimensional
            Console.WriteLine(arregloMultidimencionalValores[0, 2]);
            Console.WriteLine(arregloMultidimencionalValores[1, 2]);

 int i5 = 0;
        while (i5 < arregloMultidimencionalValores.GetLength(0))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arregloMultidimencionalValores[0,1]);
               i5++;
        }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El while es un for donde manejas el iterador a mano... podrias mostrar como hiciste el for?

Comment: No sé cómo es tu código con el for, pero seguro que a la hora de imprimir tuviste que variar los índices del arreglo. Lo que muestras siempre imprime un único valor : arregloMultidimencionalValores[0,1]

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < arregloMultidimencionalValores.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < arregloMultidimencionalValores.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(arregloMultidimencionalValores[i, j] + " ");

                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

ese es el del for

Answer (score 0):

usa este código:

```csharp
//declaracion del arreglo multidimensional con valores
int[,] arregloMultidimencionalValores = {
    {1, 3, 4},
    {5, 8, 9},
    {4, 1, 3},
    {7, 3, 4},
};

//imprimiendo la posicion de un valor del arreglo multidimensional
int i = 0;
while(i < arregloMultidimencionalValores.GetLength(0)){
    int j = 0;
    while(j < arregloMultidimencionalValores.GetLength(1)){
        Console.Write(arregloMultidimencionalValores[i, j] + " ");
        j++;
    }
    i++;
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

mira la salida:
[image: salida de ejemplo]

Comment: justo asi tengo el for, algo parecido, muchas gracias, no sabia la verdad como acomodar todo,

Comment: marca la respuesta como aceptada si te funciona la solución